# Is there any kivy package to install for webcam to display user's photo?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('frontend.kv')

class CameraScreen(Screen):

    def start(self):
        pass
    
    def stop(self):
        pass
    
    def capture(self):
        pass

class ImageScreen(Screen):
        pass
    
class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class FileSharer:
    
    def __init__(self, filepath, api_key="AVIVqp7suSQWWEdrl6hf9z"):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.api_key = api_key
    
    def share(self):
        client = Client(self.api_key)
        new_filelink = client.upload(filepath=self.filepath)
        return new_filelink.url
    
class MainApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()
    
    
    MainApp().run()
```

And this the output whenever I'm trying to run this code:

```
File "C:\Users\Webcam Photo Sharer\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 120, in init_camera
     self._resolution = (int(frame.shape[1]), int(frame.shape[0]))
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Instead of displaying the app!! Please can someone help me fix this??

Comment: The error message does not relate to the code you shared. The line of code in the error is not found in the main code, which is also not 120 lines long.

Comment: Please are you on discord so that i can show you the whole error message??

Comment: It is better if we keep this discussion here. Please edit your post, and add all relevant information there.